# Qual tipo utilizar para armazenar valores que estão em um ArrayList<> em uma tabela SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho a seguinte tabela em SQLite:

```
db.execSQL("create table amc(_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome text not null, contratada text not null, tipo text not null, data text not null, respostas integer not null, resultado float);");
```

O campo `respostas` é o seguinte lista `ArrayList<Integer> respostas = new ArrayList<>();` como eu posso salvar os valores desse `ArrayList<>` na minha tabela `amc` no campo `respostas`?

Seria possível?

Comment: O seu array list irá armazenar inteiros? crie uma coluna integer

Comment: @AndersonHenrique Sim sim, isso já está feito. Inseri mais informações na minha pergunta.

Comment: Imagino que seria melhor criar uma outra tabela, para armazenar as respostas. Vc vai precisar linkar utilizando um id (fk / pk) com a tabela amc.  Fica a dúvida se você tem um número limitado de respostas.Já que serão um campo para cada resposta na tabela Respostas.

Comment: Não altere o conteúdo da pergunta, se tem uma nova pergunta, faça uma nova.

Comment: Será que não ha necessidade de criar outra tabela? Caso não houver, tente reorganizar isso ai pra jogar em `varchar` mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARCHAR`, não tem outro jeito, você terá que converter e administrar isso no banco dados tanto para escrever quanto para ler.

Tem algumas estratégias que pode usar, o  mais comum é separar cada elemento por vírgula.

SQLite é fantástico, flexível, mas deixa tudo por sua conta fazer na mão.

Dependendo do caso o `BLOB` pode ser mais adequado.

[Tipagem do SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).